# bootstrap datepicker get users current month on the calendar

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

Using https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

my overall goal here is to refire the `beforeShowDay` on a month of my chosing. 
Now I can already do this hard coded, but I'm trying to get hold of the month the user is currently seeing.

It's easy when the calendar loads, but after that I have no way of knowing what month they have navigated to. 
I can then use this to request that months worth of data from the database.

My current solution to refire is using the onchange for month

```js
$('.datepicker').on('changeMonth', function () {
    rebuildCalendarData();
});
```

simple enough but this builds another calendar in the current month, and shifts the original calendar on to the next month.

I've tried destorying the calendar before reloading, but again, I have no idea what month they have selected.

My final idea was an attempt to read the month from the HTML tag and use that to grab my data, but binding such statement inside the dateheading doesn't work, as the grab of the heading is performed before the calendar reload, and thus gets an empty element.

```js
$('.datepicker').on('changeMonth', function () {
    dateheading = document.getElementsByClassName("datepicker-switch").innerHTML;
    rebuildCalendarData();
});
```

Has anyone had any success on attempting to do this?
I've run out of ideas on how I can get this to work.

My calendar data is here for reference

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd/m/yyyy',
    maxViewMode: 1,
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked a way around this. I edited some of the underlying library code and refine the calendar.